# jQuery expanding menu easing without css transition

Tags: javascript, css

So, I'm trying to set up a expanding and collapsing menu depending on what item you are hovering. I am using css transitions to make the expanding and collapsing smooth and some jQuery to change width css properties. However, IE doesn't support transition css so I am trying to find a way to do this with jQuery but haven't found a solution. My knowledge isn't the greatest when it comes to jQuery. Any help would be amazing.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.a{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:#852369;
position:relative;
float:left;
-webkit-transition: width 1s ease; 
-moz-transition: width 1s ease; 
-o-transition: width 1s ease;   
-ms-transition: width 1s ease;   
transition: width 1s ease;

}
.b{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:#542365;
position:relative;
float:left;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease; 
-moz-transition: width 1s ease; 
-o-transition: width 1s ease;   
-ms-transition: width 1s ease;   
transition: width 1s ease;
}
.c{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:#523641;
position:relative;
float:left;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease; 
-moz-transition: width 1s ease; 
-o-transition: width 1s ease;   
-ms-transition: width 1s ease;   
transition: width 1s ease;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>    
<div class="a">This is div a</div>
<div class="b">This is div b</div>
<div class="c">This is div c</div>​
<script>
$(function() {
$('.a').hover(function() {
    $('.b,.c').css('width', '50');
    $('.a').css('width', '200');
}, function() {
    $('.a,.b,.c').css('width', '');
}

);
$('.b').hover(function() {
    $('.a,.c').css('width', '50');
    $('.b').css('width', '200');
}, function() {
    $('.a,.b,.c').css('width', '');
}

);
$('.c').hover(function() {
    $('.a,.b').css('width', '50');
    $('.c').css('width', '200');
}, function() {
    $('.a,.b,.c').css('width', '');
}

);
});​
</script
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a simple jsfiddle of what I have currently.

http://jsfiddle.net/kevin11189/kRZHL/1/

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Is [this](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) what you want?

Comment: Can you link to a site that has similar menu effects so we can see better what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) methods to accomplish this:

http://jsfiddle.net/brianpeiris/CgY2b/2/

```
$(function() {
    var menus = $('.menu');
    menus.hover(function() {        
        menus.stop();
        $(this).animate({'width': '200'});
        menus.not(this).animate({'width': '50'});
    }, function () {
        menus.stop().animate({'width': '100'});
    });
});
```

---

```
<div class="menu a">This is div a</div>
<div class="menu b">This is div b</div>
<div class="menu c">This is div c</div>
```

---

```
.menu{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
.a{ background:#852369; }
.b{ background:#542365; }
.c{ background:#523641; }
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm looking for. However, it's really buggy when going between menus. Take a look and you'll see. Thank you for the code, though. It's progress.

Comment: I've amended my answer to fix that issue and simplify the code.